# Can I compile c++ on a MacOS X 10.8 VM to work on current macs or do I need to use a MacOS 10.12 VM?

Tags: c++, macos, virtual-machine, macos-sierra, osx-mountain-lion

I have two VM’s My MacOS X 10.8 one runs better though
So can I compile c++ code on my Mountain Lion VM to work on current macs or do I need to use my MacOS Sierra VM?

Comment: For c++ you should be ok but if using Apple frameworks then those tend to change over time so certain frameworks may not be available on newer OS versions. Did you try it and run into a problem? There's also a target setting in Xcode.

Comment: The os is backwards compatible so in general it should work. Try it and then edit your question to include the problems you encountered (if any)